# How to speed up youtube's videos more than 16x with javascript?

Tags: youtube, html5-video, playback, audiovideoplayback, mediaplayback

I use
`document.getElementsByClassName("video-stream html5-main-video")[0].playbackRate = x;` and `x` from 0 to 16. There is an error if it bigger than 16

```
VM308:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'playbackRate' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': The provided playback rate (17) is not in the supported playback range.
    at <anonymous>:1:82
```

So, how to speed it up more than 16x?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
VM308:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'playbackRate' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': The provided playback rate (17) is not in the supported playback range.
    at <anonymous>:1:82
```

`The provided playback rate (17) is not in the supported playback range.`

you cant have playback more than 16x

`0.0625<  video speed < 16`

anyways, why do you want a very high playback rate tho?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

No after 16x its not possible on the web browser itself. But you can download the video and use a media player that speeds up the video more than 16x.

For making the video speed upto 16x, the steps to do that are :-
You can just place the cursor over the youtube video that you are watching and you can just scroll up from your mouse until the video speed becomes 16x.

Enjoy :)